# Can Python Make A Function Call To R?

Tags: python, r

I have a project that I am working on in Python and a large chunk of what I want to do has already been implemented with ease in R. What I am wondering is if it is possible to make a function call to R in order to get a value from this already made code that I can then use in my own program?

Essentially, the idea would be that I could iterate through my Python program, and then in each iteration the program makes a call to R and R executes what it needs to do, and then that value in R gets thrown back into the Python program for subsequent calculations. I don't know the language needed to describe this, so it is very crude and I apologize.

Comment: See: https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/

Comment: Look rpy2 at https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/